# How can I open my documentDirectory (from my UITableView) files in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I would like my files from my iOS document directory (the files are listed in my UITableView) to be accessible, so when tapped, a UIWebView would load that file (offline).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pathForYourFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathForYourFile ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]]; 

}
```

Refer this document to find out the file formats supported by UIWebView

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Comment: no, you didn't listen to my question. I need the file which is currently selected in the UITableView to open in the WebView. I know how to open a local file in a UIWebView, just not sure how to open the file of the selected row in the UITableView...

Comment: You have to tell the system which file it has to open. It wont just grab the file by itself. Anyhow, I have updated my answer by adding contents from the previous question that u asked. I guess it might help you.